# Angular.Foreach in $firebaseObject

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I've a service Firebase that retrieves data, and that builds a array. I do a `angular.foreach` and I put the values in a table that I instantiate zero.

But it returns me an empty array.

I wish it returns me an array of objects Markers.

This is my service.

```
(function () {

  'use strict';

   angular

    .module('app.pages.cartographie')

    .factory('DeviceService', DeviceService);

/* @ngInject */

function DeviceService($injector, $q) {
   // inject another service
    var ServiceUser = $injector.get('ServiceUser');
    var userDatas = ServiceUser.getUserDatas();
    console.log('info ' + userDatas.info);
    var service = {
        getMarkers: getMarkers
    };
    return service;

    function getMarkers() {
        // firebase Promise
        userDatas.$loaded().then(function () {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            var devices = userDatas.ownDevices;
            console.log('Device ' + devices);
            var markers = [];
            angular.forEach(devices, function (key) {
                var devicesData = firebase.database().ref().child('device/' + key).once('value');
                devicesData.then(function (data) {
                    var deviceObj = data.val();
                    markers.push({
                        lat: deviceObj.lat,
                        lng: deviceObj.lng
                    });
                });
            });
            $q.all(markers).then(function () {
                // 
                console.log('markers ' + JSON.stringify(markers));
            });
            return defer;
        });
    }
}})();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `markers.push()` in your code is going to happen long after you call `$q.all(markers)`, so `markers` is going to be empty when you call `$q.all(markers)`.

I think you should be able to remedy this like so:

```
function getMarkers() {
    // firebase Promise
    return userDatas.$loaded().then(function () {
        var devices = userDatas.ownDevices;
        console.log('Device ' + devices);

        var markers = devices.map(function (key) {
            var devicesData = firebase.database().ref().child('device/' + key).once('value');

            return devicesData.then(function (data) {
                var deviceObj = data.val();

                return {
                    lat: deviceObj.lat,
                    lng: deviceObj.lng
                };
            });
        });

        return $q.all(markers)
            // the next three lines are not necessary and are just for debugging
            .finally(function (retrievedMarkers) {
                console.log('markers ' + JSON.stringify(retrievedMarkers));
            });
    });
}
```

I would also suggest refactoring this so that you're not doing too much in one function:

```
// returns a promise for one set of coordinates
function getDeviceCoordinates(deviceKey) {
    var devicesData = firebase.database().ref().child('device/' + key).once('value');

    return devicesData.then(function (data) {
        var deviceObj = data.val();

        return {
            lat: deviceObj.lat,
            lng: deviceObj.lng
        };
    });
}

function getMarkers() {
    // firebase Promise
    return userDatas.$loaded().then(function () {
        var devices = userDatas.ownDevices;
        console.log('Device ' + devices);

        var markers = devices.map(getDeviceCoordinates);

        return $q.all(markers)
            // the next three lines are not necessary and are just for debugging
            .finally(function (retrievedMarkers) {
                console.log('markers ' + JSON.stringify(retrievedMarkers));
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I've tried the two solutions but in the two case, markers is indefined.

Comment: @YseultFran I don't see any way that `markers` could be undefined. Could you show me how you are trying to access it?

Comment: In my controller  I have `vm.markers = DeviceService.getMarkers();`

Comment: And the  `.finally(function (retrievedMarkers) {
                console.log('markers ' + JSON.stringify(retrievedMarkers));
            });`

Comment: @YseultFran Ok,thank you, and are you saying that `vm.markers` is undefined after that? Have you used entire functions exactly as I wrote them, or did you modify them?

Comment: The console.log is undefined.

Comment: I use your function exactely

Comment: `var devices = userDatas.ownDevices;
                console.log('Device ' + devices);
                // Device ,00000,00001,00002
                var markers = devices.map(getDeviceCoordinates);
                 console.log('markers ' + JSON.stringify(markers));
                 // markers = markers [null,{},{},{}]`

Comment: @YseultFran Could you show me your full code, in its current state, in pastebin or something?

Comment: I've created a plnkr

Comment: @YseultFran I don't know why there's a null at the beginning of `markers` when you log it, but the markers are not going to have values at that point in the code so it doesn't make sense to log them there. Does the `console.log()` inside the `finally` part ever write to the console, or is that part never written?

Comment: In the finally part, the console.log wrote "undefined".